# Stored procedure table parameter versus xml in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got two versions of a stored procedure that does basically the same - does a right join query on a largish table and another table that is provided as a parameter.

- The first version takes a string with XML and does a select from `OPENXML`.
- The second takes the provided table variable parameter.

I expected the second/table version to outperform the first/XML version as it doesn't do any parsing, doc object creating and disposing explicitly. My test show, however, that both versions get executed in approx the same time.

What might be the reason? Table parameter serializes worse than string parameter? XML queries are very efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the execution plan.

My impression is that most of the effort is not in the serializing of the XML, but in the actual join, which will be the same for both options